# Find the missing number in the series 84, 81, 88, 14, 12, 18, 9, ?, 11

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a question which is troubling me from 2 days, could anyone help me in understanding this question with solution? It is a multiple choice question with options 16, 10, 12, 14. ([Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drTzF.jpg))

> \begin{array}{c}  84 & 81 & 88 \\ 14 & 12 & 18 \\ 9 & ? & 11 \end{array}

Comment: I would also point out that the square shape may have an importance there.

Comment: It could be anything, an infinite amount of polynomial a can  go through our numbers.

Comment: There are 4 options mentioned in MCQ (multiple choice question) i have to chose from them.

Comment: I suspect the general feeling regarding this problem is contempt for its creator: It essentially requires one to read the mind of wrote it, and none of us are in a position to know that. It's a puzzle, not a math problem.

Comment: I fear it is $(a) 16$ because of $27$ from this [link](https://books.google.com/books?id=hTlVAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA90-IA94&lpg=PA90-IA94) and since the numbers in the first line will then all be half product of two numbers in the square (and yes it is ugly!)

Comment: @RaymondManzoni In that case, I presume the pattern is best understood by splitting up the square as $\{84,14,12\}$, $\{81,18,9\}$, $\{88,?,11\}$ and note that the first number in the first two triplets is twice the product of other two numbers. (Which is perfectly coherent but quite arbitrary.)

Comment: Yay . . thanks @RaymondManzoni write this as answer i will mark it as solution :)

Comment: @Semiclassical: Yes that is the point in the link or in question $32$ page $6$ of [this one](http://theinstituteedu.com/sscpaper/6.pdf) but the problem may be different here...

Comment: @user127467: it could be the wished answer but a nicer one could exist... anyway at SE the OP (you) is encouraged to provide an answer so...

Comment: Here's a link http://www.ssgan.8m.com/mathr.html where the give the same answer as Raymanon Manzoni and semiclassical bu the numbers are in a different order.  84, 14, 12, 81, 18, 9, 88, ? ,11. (so 84 = 14.12/2; 81= 189/2) It's clear by Raymond Manzoni that this is the assumed answer but as there is absolutely no pattern in how to arrange them I'm assuming the typesetter of the book simply got the order wrong.  Randomly rearranging the numbers so that they form triplets but not in order with that pattern, is simply not an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was from a cheap book and they printed it wrong that's why i was not able to make the connection between numbers, The actual problem is:
$$\{84,14,12\}, \{81,18,9\},  \{88,?,11\}$$

Thanks to  Raymond Manzoni
\begin{align}
\left(\frac {84}{12}= 7\right) &\times 2 = 14\\
\left(\frac {81}{9} = 9\right) &\times 2 = 18\\
\end{align}
Hence the answer
$$\left(\frac {88}{11} = 8\right) \times 2 = 16$$

Comment: This "Actual Problem" is quite different from the wording of the first post, so I am going to downvote it.

Comment: @GCab What matters is i found my solution :) , Upvote , Downvote doesn't matter, and i don't think that's the core purpose of stackexchange. Do whatever you want.

Answer (score 7):

The missing term is $16$. It is rather obvious that the stated numbers are the values of $P(1), P(2),\ldots,P(9)$ of the polynomial $P(x) = (361 x^8)/13440-(2335 x^7)/2016+(20179 x^6)/960-(37483 x^5)/180+(781069 x^4)/640-(1232443 x^3)/288+(9657237 x^2)/1120-(7518241 x)/840+3659$

Comment: I forgot to mention : 
Solution options are : 
1.16
2.10 
3.12 
4.14 
It is a Multiple Choice Question

Comment: can you explain in nobee ways . . the way you are expressing seems too complex to understand :(

Comment: @user127467 I'm assume that this answer is meant to be a tongue in cheek joke.  For any sequence of k numbers, one can construct a polynomial P(x)  where those numbers are the answers to P(1), P(2), etc. Thus we can make the missing number anything we want.  The question isn't what does the number *have* to be as it can be anything, but what is the *simplest* answer.  As "simplicity" is subjective what these questions actually want is not clear.  That is why so many of us *HATE* these question and refuse to answer them.

Comment: [Poe's law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poe%27s_law) seems relevant here...

Comment: no seriously. . believe me this question is from a book and i have posted a snap image of the question.

Comment: As an example:  What is the missing number 1,4,9,X,25.  I want it to be 107.  Because I want P(x) = $ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx+ e$ to be P(1) = 1; P(2)=4; P(3) = 9; P(4) = 107; P(5)= 25.  I can find a polynomial where this is true by solving $a + b + c + d +e = 1$; $16a + 8b + 4c + 2d +e=2$; $81a + 27b + 9c + 3d + e=9$; $256a + 64b + 16c + 4d + e = 107$; and $625a + 125b + 25c+5d + e = 25$.  Thus I can argue that the answer can be 107.  Or anything I want.

Comment: I'm sure it's a real question.  We are just saying we hate books that ask these questions.  The book probably thinks that some rule involving multiplying things and subtracting square roots from the sums of the digits is the answer.  But the answer could be anything and stumbling upon the one the book think is right is just chance.

Answer (score 4):

None of the above, it must be 42.

Comment: based on what ?

Comment: @ G Cab you really take this question and answers seriously?

Comment: Oh i am sorry. . what is wrong with this question ?

Comment: @frank000, well, like all quizzes of that type, it is a challenging "hunting" exercise to find the simplest matching relation

Comment: @frank000 If it was asked it was a serious question to someone.  I, like just about everyone here, *hate* these types of problems.  Theoretically there can be any answer as a sequence need not have any rules and can be as arbitrary as one likes. Despite my objections "hunting" for "simple" are considered acceptable questions.  I look for simple progressions by subtracting terms and if I can't see something in 30 seconds then I figure the answer isn't simple enough to be a valid question.  With the jump from 88 to 14 this has no simple answer and I reject it.

Comment: @GCab based on "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy".  This was not a serious answer as frank000 does not consider this a serious question.

Comment: @frank000 good for you  . . but this is serious for me . . and if it is not serious for you then why answer ?